# CI4 Shield not updating 'last_active ' field in users table

Tags: codeigniter-4

Im working with CodeIgniter 4 and shield for user management, I want to show 'last_active' but is always null.

In auth config I enable:

```
public bool $recordActiveDate = true;
```

but still nothing, is there anything Im missing?

Comment: Ok I got help from the developer, to solve the issue have to set filters according to the guide: [link](https://codeigniter4.github.io/shield/install/#protect-all-pages)

Answer (score 1):

Use this code in your app/Config/Filters.php

```
 public array $globals = [
    'before' => [
        // 'honeypot',
        // 'csrf',
        // 'invalidchars',
        'session' => ['except' => ['login*', 'register', 'auth/a/*', 'logout']],
    ],
```

make sure you are adding that code after allowing this public bool $recordActiveDate = true; in vendor/codeigniter4/shied/src/Config/Auth.php